# Update TextBox C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm new in GUI development, especially in C#. I'm not able to update the UI when I change internally the property Text of a TextBox.
I know there an TextChanged Event, but I think it is fired only when an user types into the textbox.

Here is my code :

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int curItem = this.listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    StockItem it = this.model.Items.ElementAt(curItem);
    this.itemNameTextBox.Text = it.Name;
    this.supplierTextBox.Text = it.Supplier;
    this.unitCostTextBox.Text = it.UnitCost.ToString();
    this.nbRequiredTextBox.Text = it.NbRequired.ToString();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  What is currently happening.  You modify a text box's text property by assigning to it text (in addition, a string).

Comment: Please specify what event this is hooked up to and if this is WPF, Winforms, etc.

Also, is your concern that an event doesn't fire when you modify the text property of a control?

Comment: you are talking about winforms right, not webforms?

Comment: @Rikon: While it's technically possible, I doubt this is web development - he's talking about capturing a text changed event with C# and he didn't even mention the word javascript.

Comment: You should check that you don't have another event that is rewriting default values after the IndexChanged event fires.  I've had that issue occur in the past.

Comment: Yeah, but if he's new to web UI, he may not be aware of webforms postback model... I was just clarifying...

Comment: @JonH: When the user clicks on an element of the list box (which fires up an SelectIndexChanged event), I want to set the Text in some TextBox, located in another panel. I think my code is coherent with my words so far. Once their property Text has been modified, no change is visible on the UI. It is on this point I struggle. I Use System.Windows.Forms. And it's not web development. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the text of the list box does not cause the selected index to change.

If you want listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged to fire, you will need to search the list box for the text you want to set it to, grab that index, then set the selectedIndex.

I'm assuming that's what you're trying to do.